# Java and command line arguments

Tags: java, command-line-arguments

So I'm fairly new to java and have been learning for the past couple months or so, and I'm really struggling with command line arguments. Not so much the concept, but how to implement them (sorry if that's the wrong term usage) in [IntelliJ IDEA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA)? and the command line really. In my lab for class (not graded, just not mandatory help), it says I can pass as many String values as I want (makes sense..)

And then has:

```
demo$ java MyProgram str1 str2 str3
```

When I try to run this in the terminal with the copied code from the lab assignment, I keep getting a:

> demo $ is not recognized

What's going on?

The code we are supposed to use is:

```
public class TestCLArgs {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        System.out.println("Received command line args: ");
        for(String arg : args) {
            System.out.println(arg);
        }
    }
}
```

And then we're supposed to run it in the terminal by typing

```
demo $ javac TestCLArgs.java
demo $ java TestCLArgs hello world 1 2 3
```

Comment: what was your question again?

Comment: Which OS are you using? Windows, Mac, *Nix?

Comment: demo $ is just the command prompt. If you are using Windows, it will look like C:\Windows> or something ..

Comment: It is highly likely that you are using windows and you are blindly copying "demo $"

Answer (score 2):

Try run just this:

```
    java MyProgram str1 str2 str3
```

Answer (score 0):

`demo $` is the prompt , probably given in some book that you are following. You don't have to type that.

All you have to type is `java MyProgram str1 str2 str3`